# assignment operator overloading in arrays

Tags: c++

I tried the below code but I got error.
I am getting error in that overloading assignment operator..
SO, please do check what my mistake is:
Is my syntax of operator overloading correct?
I want that particular thing to be solved.

```
    #include<bits/stdc++.h>
    #include<iostream>
    using namespace std;
    class complex
    {
        int n,i;
        int *x=new int[n];
        int *y=new int[n];
        public:
        complex(int n)
        {
            cout<<"enter values of x:"<<endl;
            for(i=0;i<n;i++)
            cin>>*(x+i);
            cout<<"values of x are:"<<endl;
            for(i=0;i<n;i++)
            cout<<*(x+i)<<endl;
        }
        complex operator =(complex *y)
        {
            cout<<"values of y are:"<<endl;
            for(i=0;i<n;i++)
            {
                *(y+i)=*(x+i);
                cout<<*(y+i)<<endl;
            }
        }
        complex(complex &)
        {
            cout<<"copy constructor called:"<<endl;
        }
        ~complex()
        {
            cout<<"destructorr called:"<<endl;
        }
    };
    int main()
    {
        complex obj1(5);
        complex obj2(obj1);
        obj2=obj1;
        return 0;
    }
```

Errors I got:
In member function 'complex complex::operator=(complex *)
[Error] no match for 'operator<<' (operand types are 'std::ostream {aka std::basic_ostream}' and 'complex')

Comment: why are you not using `std::vector` ? Your `complex` is seriously broken. And please incldue the error message in the question

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_assignment
class_name & class_name :: operator= ( const class_name & )

Comment: I posted an answer, please first compile and run it and then study it. Then let me know if it solved the problem

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many errors in your code.

The reason for most of them is that since you have `using namespace std;` compiler mistakes your complex with its own complex library so the

```
In member function 'complex complex::operator=(complex *) [Error] no match for 'operator<<' (operand types are 'std::ostream {aka std::basic_ostream}' and 'complex')
```

error. Never use `using namespace std;` and save your self so much trouble in the future!

For copy assignment and constructor you should get const reference of the same type and change all the variable accordingly to be an exact copy of another!

Also don't forget that return type of copy assignment should be reference!

Since this is your first question here, I corrected all the mistakes and added few helpful things. Just follow and use the comments:

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h> // you don't need this for this example
#include<iostream>
//using namespace std;   <-- never use this. it is very bad!
class complex
{
    int n; // yu don't need i
    int *x=new int[n];
    int *y=new int[n];
    public:
    complex(int n_value):n(n_value) // <--first initialize n like this
    {
        std::cout<<"enter values of x:"<<std::endl;
        for(int i=0;i<n;++i) // <-- try to use pre-increment instead
        std::cin>>*(x+i);
        std::cout<<"enter values of y:"<<std::endl; //<-- do not forget about the other dynamic array
        for(int i=0;i<n;++i) // <-- try to use pre-increment instead
        std::cin>>*(y+i);

        std::cout<<"values of x and y are:"<<std::endl;
        for(int i=0;i<n;++i){ // <-- try to use pre-increment instead
            std::cout<<"x[" << i << "] is " << *(x+i)<<std::endl;
            std::cout<<"y[" << i << "] is " << *(y+i)<<std::endl;
        }
    }
    complex& /*here the return type should be reference of the type*/ operator =(const complex& another)// for this operator you should get another variable of this type as const reference
    {
        delete[] x; // <-- do NOT forget to delete the dynamic memory first
        delete[] y; // <-- do NOT forget to delete the dynamic memory first
        n = another.n; //reassign n from another
        //call for another dynamic memory again
        x=new int[n];
        y=new int[n];

        std::cout<<"values of y and x are:"<<std::endl;
        for(int i=0;i<n;++i) // <-- try to use pre-increment instead
        {
            *(x+i) = *(another.x+i);
            *(y+i) = *(another.y+i); // do not forget about the other dynamic array, the y
            std::cout<<"x[" << i << "] is " << *(x+i)<<std::endl;
            std::cout<<"y[" << i << "] is " << *(y+i)<<std::endl;
        }
        return *this; //
    }
    complex(const complex & another):n(another.n) // <--first initialize n like this // for this operator you should get another variable of this type as const reference
    {
        //here, try this one your self! Tip it is like assignment operator!
        std::cout<<"copy constructor called:"<<std::endl;
    }
    ~complex()
    {
        std::cout<<"destructorr called:"<<std::endl;
    }
};
int main()
{
    complex obj1(5);
    complex obj2(obj1);
    obj2=obj1;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: thanks for your detailed explanation, I understood it well..

Comment: @Bhavana Thank YOU for your question. if my answer helped please consider accepting it by clicking on the tick-like sign beside my answer and you will receive 2 points!